# Storybook cannot find Angular Material core when using a custom theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, storybook

I'm trying to configure Storybook for Angular (v13.0.0). Everything is working (I can write stories for basic components), except that I cannot find a way to make [Angular Material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)#Angular_Material) styles work. What I have done so far:

- Include the style sheets added by Angular Material in the page header (for MatIcon and also the font)  => this is working as expected
- Add the `@storybook/preset-scss` to my dependencies and also to the `.storybook/main.js` addons (as explained in the README)
- Make sure that the `angular.json` includes my `styles.scss` file

This is a brand new project and I haven't done anything to the style sheet that has been generated by Angular Material (I'm using a custom theme). Everything is all right when I use my components in the web application (styles are correctly applied), but the storybook components cannot load Angular Material styles. When I open the console, I have a warning saying that the Angular Material core cannot be found, and therefore I have partial styles applied and I can't use the components correctly. I never used Storybook before, so I'm not sure if the issue is related to the custom theme or not; the solutions I find on Stack Overflow and GitHub all mention the prebuilt themes.

What am I missing?

Comment: How did you include your styles.scss in your angular.json? Can you provide a code snippet?